# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'stationName')

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, web, error-handling

Please forgive me for the silly question, but I honestly can't fix this. I have searched all over and I still can't understand what's causing the error.

I am learning how to code, and one of the exercises I was tasked with id to create a basic app. However I am using jQuery and PHP (which I only have a superficial understanding off).

I am able to connect and receive a response, however, when I am trying to update the html with the info from the api, it does not work, and I get this error in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'stationName')

Please see the code here below:

HTML

```
<h2>Airport Weather</h2>

<select id="selectAirport">
  <option value="LPPR">Porto</option>
  <option value="LZZH">Zurich</option>
  <option value="LFPO">Paris</option>
  <option value="EGLC">London</option>
</select>
<button id="btnRun">Check weather</button>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Airport Name:</td>
    <td id="aiport"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Time:</td>
    <td id="time"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Temperature:</td>
    <td id="temp"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Humidity:</td>
    <td id="humidity"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Clouds:</td>
    <td id="clouds"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Wind Direction:</td>
    <td id="windDirection"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Wind Speed:</td>
    <td id="windSpeed"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$('#btnRun').click(function () {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'php/getUrl.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
      search: $('#selectAirport').val(),
    },
    success: function (result) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(result));

      if (result.status.name == 'ok') {
        $('#airport').html(result['data'][0]['stationName']);
        $('#time').html(result['data'][0]['datetime']);
        $('#clouds').html(result['data'][0]['clouds']);
        $('#windDirection').html(result['data'][0]['windDirection']);
        $('#windSpeed').html(result['data'][0]['windSpeed']);
        $('#temp').html(result['data'][0]['temperature']);
        $('#humidity').html(result['data'][0]['humidity']);
      }
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      //
    },
  });
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php

// remove for production

ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$executionStartTime = microtime(true);


$url = 'http://api.geonames.org/weatherIcaoJSON?ICAO=' . $_REQUEST['search'] . '&username=joselages';


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

$decode = json_decode($result, true);

$output['status']['code'] = "200";
$output['status']['name'] = "ok";
$output['status']['description'] = "success";
$output['status']['returnedIn'] = intval((microtime(true) - $executionStartTime) * 1000) . " ms";
$output['data'] = $decode['weatherObservation'];


header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');

echo json_encode($output);

?>
```

Can someone please be kind enough to tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thank you for your patience

Comment: The problem seems to be in `result`, specifically in `result['data'][0]['stationName']`. Now we don't know what this result looks like, but your error says that `result['data'][0]` does not exist.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware, thank you for your help, this is what result looks like:
{"status":{"code":"200","name":"ok","description":"success","returnedIn":"92 ms"},"data":{"elevation":73,"lng":-8.666666666666666,"observation":"LPPR 112330Z 10005KT 040V110 CAVOK 07/00 Q1027","ICAO":"LPPR","clouds":"clouds and visibility OK","dewPoint":"0","cloudsCode":"CAVOK","datetime":"2023-02-11 23:30:00","countryCode":"PT","temperature":"7","humidity":61,"stationName":"Porto / Pedras Rubras","weatherCondition":"n/a","windDirection":100,"hectoPascAltimeter":1027,"windSpeed":"05","lat":41.21666666666667}}

Comment: result is being returned, I just dont get how why I am not able to update the innerHtml from data. I bet that it's something really silly and I am too tired to find it. but it has been making my head in.

Comment: It doesn't look like `result['data']` is an array, but an object. This suggests you want `result['data']['stationName']` (or, alternatively, 
 `result.data.stationName`).

Comment: jQuery('#airport').html(result['data']['stationName']); .You can show the data in this format.Here in result data is a seperate array so no need to use [0] here